# Determining Proxy Used by Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, developer-tools

I'm utilizing a Firefox extension that enables me to connect to a specific website using a proxy. The website is inaccessible without this extension. I'm wondering if it's possible to identify the proxy being used by the extension at any given moment using the Developer Tools or something else. So I can connect to the website with wget in the terminal.